# redirect stdout and stderr to different processes

Tags: c, bash, shell, io-redirection

I am testing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112979/pipe-stdout-and-stderr-to-two-different-processes-in-shell-script) but when I use a C program instead of bash script, I couldn't get it to work properly.

This is the C program.

```
// tss.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   while (1)
   {
      fprintf(stdout, "stdout: sias\n");
      fprintf(stderr, "stderr: cias\n");
      sleep(5);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

This is the test result, where I only see stderr not stdout.

```
$ $ { tss 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | sed -u 's/^/err: /'; } 3>&1 1>&2 | sed -u 's/^/out: /'
err: stderr: cias
err: stderr: cias
```

I then notice that I need to do "fflush(stdout)" in the program. But one thing I don't understand why it is not needed for stderr, and is there a way to get it to work without inserting fflush?

Comment: Does ["C equivalent of autoflush (flush stdout after each write)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214271/c-equivalent-of-autoflush-flush-stdout-after-each-write) answer your question?

Comment: Re "*I only see stderr not stdout.*", That's only because you didn't wait long enough. When the buffer fills or the program exits, the buffer will be output. Note that the `unbuffer` tool can be used to fool STDOUT back into line-buffered behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then notice that I need to do "fflush(stdout)" in the program. But one thing I don't understand why it is not needed for stderr,

`stdout` is buffered by default -- line buffered when it is connected to a terminal, but block buffered otherwise.  Connecting the program's stdout to a pipe produces the "otherwise" case.  `fflush()` is how you send the buffered output to the pipe before the buffer fills.

`stderr` is unbuffered by default.  Unless you change that, output to `stderr` is sent to the output device immediately.

> and is there a way to get it to work without inserting fflush?

Without `fflush()`, the output to `stdout` will be emitted in buffer-size chunks.  If you want stdout to be unbuffered instead, like stderr, then you can achieve that with [`setvbuf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf).